# Reindexing in R with data.table?

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, lookup, lapply

Here is a frequent problem i've come across recently in R with `data.table`

I have an index table, say DT1. The column x would be a subset of indexes. I would be working with a subtable of a bigger rawtable using these indexes. the subtable typically would be indexed from 1 to N. (thats the column y)

then for example, i would come across a table with pairs of indexes with the original indexing, and i want to know the corresponding new indexing.

Here's what it looks like

```
DT1 <- data.table(x=c(0,3,5),y= c(11,22,33))
DT2 <- data.table(x=c(3,3,0,0,5),x=c(0,5,0,3,5))
# > DT1
#    x y
# 1: 0 11
# 2: 3 22
# 3: 5 33

# > DT2
#    x x
# 1: 3 0
# 2: 3 5
# 3: 0 0
# 4: 0 3
# 5: 5 5
```

Here is a tortuous way i found

```
cbind(DT1[DT2[,1,with=FALSE],on="x"][,2,with=FALSE],DT1[DT2[,2,with=FALSE],on="x"][,2,with=FALSE])
#     y  y
# 1: 22 11
# 2: 22 33
# 3: 11 11
# 4: 11 22
# 5: 33 33
```

a more basic way to do this with `sapply` gives the same result

```
tab=DT1$x
lookup <- function(value){DT1$y[which(tab==value)]}

colnames(DT2) <- c("x","xx")

ans <- as.data.table(cbind(sapply(DT2$x,lookup),sapply(DT2$xx,lookup)))
colnames(ans) <- c("y","y")
```

However, 
the first solution looks a bit ugly to me

I don't like the second one, because I need to define assign a value to tab each time i use the function lookup in `lapply`.
if I had to lookup in different tables, i would have the choice either to create a new lookup function specific to that table, or to store in memory in a (temp) variable tab.
perhaps there is a way to do the `lapply` with a function of two variables
 `lookup <-function (tab,value) {...}` ? that i don't know

I'm sure there are many other ways.
I'm not sure what i'm doing exactly with the first solution. basically the syntax in `data.table` has to do with (inner and outer) JOINS. but in the final output, i want to keep the original order of the table DT2. setting column x as a key for DT2 would sort that column, making stuff like `merge` being not adapted to that ?

I'm willing to hear from you what is the best implementation, - i'm sure there are many better ones - and also , the most efficient when dealing with very very large tables.

Comment: `DT2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) factor(x, levels = DT1$x, labels = DT1$y))]`?

Comment: great, thanks ! what does the .SD mean ?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - very neat codewise, though this is using `data.frame` syntax in parts. I'm not sure of a neat way around that though.

Comment: @thelatemail, are you referring to the use of `$`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - yep, i feel like there must be a way of doing this with joins, which would be quicker I think. But I'm too dim-witted to know what that answer is :-)

Comment: @FaguiCurtain, from `?data.table`: *.SD is a data.table containing the Subset of x's Data for each group, excluding any columns used in by (or keyby).* Since we don't specify any "by", `.SD` applies here to all the columns.

Comment: @thelatemail, do you feel more comfortable with `[[` than `$` :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto - it was more that `data.table` has first merging that would be quicker than `match` - `setkey(DT1, x); setnames(DT2, c("x1","x2")); setkey(DT2, x1);  setkey(DT2[DT1], x2)[DT1]` was the best I could manage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiomatic *data.table* approach would be to *update* `DT2` while *joining* as follows:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6
setnames(DT2, c("a", "b")) # no duplicate names!!
for (nm in names(DT2)) {
    DT2[DT1, paste0(nm, ".val") := y, on = structure("x", names=nm)]
}
DT2[]
#    a b a.val b.val
# 1: 3 0    22    11
# 2: 3 5    22    33
# 3: 0 0    11    11
# 4: 0 3    11    22
# 5: 5 5    33    33
```

---

You can hide the loop with `lapply()` perhaps. If `DT2` was instead as follows (in long form; see `DT3`):

```
DT3 = melt(DT2, measure = c("a", "b"), variable.name = "id", value.name = "x.val")
```

then you could do:

```
DT3[DT1, y.val := y, on = c(x.val = "x")]
```

You can use `y.val := i.y` to be more explicit that you're referring to the `y` column from the data.table corresponding to `i` argument.. (useful when they both have common column names).

Comment: is there a way to avoid the for loop ?

Comment: Not with the way you've your `DT2` structured. What's wrong with a for-loop?

Comment: Edited to show how `DT2` should be so as to do it with one join.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following:

```
DT2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) DT1[["y"]][match(x, DT1[["x"]])])]
#     x  x
# 1: 22 11
# 2: 22 33
# 3: 11 11
# 4: 11 22
# 5: 33 33
str(.Last.value)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: num  22 22 11 11 33
#  $ x: num  11 33 11 22 33
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: thank you all, many useful answers.... actually so many answers now i don't know which one to choose in practice...